# decrypting a AES-256 encrypted file not working

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography

I use the Botan library for encrypting and my encrypting code looks like below.

```
  LibraryInitializer init;
  AutoSeeded_RNG rng;
  string passphrase="mypassword";


  PBKDF* pbkdf = get_pbkdf("PBKDF2(SHA-256)");
  SecureVector<byte> salt = rng.random_vec(16);
  InitializationVector iv(rng,16);
  OctetString aes256_key = pbkdf->derive_key(32, passphrase,&salt[0],   salt.size(), 10000 );
  cout<<"Encryption key : " << aes256_key.as_string() <<endl ;


 ifstream infile ("readme.txt");
 ofstream outfile ("encrypt.txt");



Pipe pipe(get_cipher("AES-256/EAX", aes256_key,iv, ENCRYPTION) );


pipe.start_msg();
infile>>pipe;
pipe.end_msg();

SecureVector<byte> cl = pipe.read_all();

outfile.write((const char*)cl.begin(), cl.size());


outfile.flush();
outfile.close();
infile.close();
```

this code looks working great and encrypt the input file. i posted this code to determine if there is an error in the encryption. (but I assume that the encryption is done correctly)

now the above encrypted file is tried to decrypt by the following code.

```
ifstream infile2 ("encrypt.txt");
ofstream outfile2 ("decrypt.txt");




Pipe pipe2 (get_cipher("AES-256/EAX", aes256_key, iv, DECRYPTION) );


pipe2.start_msg();
infile2 >> pipe2;
pipe2.end_msg();

SecureVector<byte> cl2 = pipe2.read_all();

outfile2.write((const char*)cl2.begin(), cl2.size());

outfile2.close();
infile2.close();
}
```

the same above generated decryption key and the `InitializationVector iv` is used for the decryption.

the decryption throws an exception `AES-256/EAX : message authentication failed`

what am I doing wrong here and how to decrypt the above encryptrd file correctly.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same key and IV *bit for bit*? As you are currently printing out random bytes as if they are printable characters.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes yes im using the same values. though i wrote the encryptrion and decryption codes seperatly here this is written in one program as two finctions. the same genereted velues are passed for both functions.

Comment: as I know even if the key is different it should decrypt the file, but not producing the original file, am i correct. I am new to cryptography.

Comment: Its not the *same*, as in the very same *instance* of `iv` you're passing right? Most AES encoders modify the IV along the encryption process. It has to be the identical IV *starting data* you used for encryption when starting the decryption. The key obviously has to be the same,

Comment: @danialweaber No, that's not the case for authenticated (AEAD) ciphers such as EAX. Incorrect keys, IV's or ciphertext will result in the error you are now getting. Only a single bit has to be wrong...

Comment: @WhozCraig Usually API's don't change the arguments passed to them, fortunately. During AES encryption the state does indeed change from block to block but normally that is contained within the cipher object. Botan is a relatively high level API, I would not *expect* the IV to change.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes what i realy do here is in the main function i generate the key and IV bit, then pass it to the encrypting function and then to the decrypting  function. so those values used for encryption and decryption should be exactly the same, but why does the decryption throws that exception

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I wouldn't rule it out unless you're familiar with the implementation itself or have tested the actual IV for same-content before and after an encryption. If you *know* they don't modify the IV, then I stand corrected. Most implementations I've seen *do* modify the IV if for no other reason than to allow continuous encryption on separate calls and pipes. So I'm interested if you know this for *sure*. Of course, we could both be off-base and the OP may be using the identical *line* of code (thus another  random IV shooting holes in their own boat). We don't have that code =(

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the `SecureVector` + file handling. Usually this kind of thing is due to some kind of encoding issue. The botan sample code uses `std::ifstream in(‘‘data.bin’’, std::ios::binary)`, probably the ciphertext is handled as characters in the code above.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes perfect whozCraig, that was excatly the mistake i was doing. you give it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Heh, which one was right and which one was wrong?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes the mistake was in file handling, you give it as an answer so i can accept it as the answer now. thanks a lot. i wouldnt have figure it out alone. thanks again. :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Nice!. Post that up and I'll tick it for sure.

Comment: @WhozCraig The IV is (in the end) passed as a `const std:vector<byte>` if I follow the code. That should mean that the IV is never changed but with C++ it's hard to be 100% sure. The intent seems to be there however.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes you're totally right. Nice job noticing the sample vs Op's usage of a binary vs text stream. answer upticked.

Comment: Save the salt (may be in clear) and input the password. You could prefix the salt (and possibly the IV) to the ciphertext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `ifstream` and `ofstream` assumes character output. If you configure it to handle binary by using `std::ios::binary` as second argument then your code should be alright. This is also used by the Botan API reference *if* it doesn't explicitly *encode* the ciphertext as well.